# Identifying a electrical smd component (probably regulator) with the marking bQCSB

Tags: voltage-regulator, identification

[image]

The description on the component is bQCSB (circled in GREEN), I'm trying to identify it to order a replacement but can't find it.

The device in question is a DJI Vista FPV transmitter.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [Silergy SY8303AAIC](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2204181630_Silergy-Corp-SY8303AAIC_C2937216.pdf) step-down converter.

[image]